# Is there a way to track detect on app install (Android or iOS) if they have or never before installed the app?

Tags: android, ios, installation

`Scenario 1: User downloads app. Deletes it. Reinstalls it 2 weeks later.`

`Scenario 2: User downloads app for the first time.`

Is there any way to separate these 2 events and detect which one it is? With Android and iOS.

Comment: You could use Keychain for this (although this is not the use case for keychain). 
A better way would be a database you fill on your server.